# Updating my files to recently committed github repo

Tags: git, github

I'm currently working on a projects with my partner, and he forked the repo and made changes, and than pushed it.

I assume my project on my computer won't automatically update to his changes, right?

So how do I make sure all my files and settings are in sync with the most recent commit?

Comment: How about `git pull`?

Comment: Downvoted for lack of research on op's part. The answer could have been easily obtained by doing a simple web search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways in which you can do this:

- Use **git fetch** to retrieve new work done by other people. Fetching from a repository grabs all the new remote-tracking branches and tags without merging those changes into your own branches.
- If you already have a local repository with a remote URL set up for the desired project, you can grab all the new information by using `git fetch *remotename*` in the terminal:
- Then doing a `git merge`

OR

- `git pull` is a convenient shortcut for completing both `git fetch` and `git merge` in the same command
- Syntax: `git pull remotename branchname`
  will grab online updates and merges them with your local work

Comment: So doing 'git pull' will pull the most recent commit and automatically replace & update my files on my hard drive? 
Also, *remotename* is the name of the repo, right?

Comment: Yes, by doing a 'git pull' the files on your hard drive will be updated by the most recent commit. You are right the remotename is the name of the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you both are working on the same branch, you'll have to do a [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) to obtain your friend modifications and then to merge into your local branch.